# While Loop Ending Early in Python?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

For some reason my while loop is stopping after two tries and I can't figure out what's wrong...
It's supposed to be an ant farm, where you can choose to breed and make a new ant, etc. 
I just don't understand why it's stopping...
Here's my code:

```
import random

class Colony(object):
    workerAnts = 0
    list = []
    temp = []
    foodAmount = 10
    def breedWorker(self):
        if Colony.foodAmount < 5:
             print "Sorry! You do not have enough food to create a new worker ant!"
        else:
                Colony.foodAmount -= 5
                Colony.workerAnts += 1
                Colony.list.append("ant")
    def step(self):
        number = 'ant'
        for number in Colony.list:
            a = Ant()
            a.forage()
            if Colony.foodAmount > 0:
                Colony.foodAmount -= 1
            if Colony.foodAmount < len(Colony.list):
                for number in Colony.list[Colony.foodAmount+1:]:
                    Ant.health -= 1
    def purge(self):
        number = 'ant'
        for number in Colony.list:
            if Ant.health > 0:
                Colony.temp.append("ant")
        Colony.list = Colony.temp       

class Ant(object):  
    health = 10
    def forage(self):
        if Ant.health == 0:
            Colony.workerAnts -= 1
        if random.randint(0,100) > 95:
            Ant.health = 0
            print "Ant has died from a horrible accident!"
            Colony.workerAnts -= 1
        elif random.randint(0,100) < 40:
            newFood = random.randint(1,5)
            print "Ant has found %s food!!" % newFood
            Colony.foodAmount += newFood    
        elif random.randint(0,100) < 5:
            Ant.health = 10
            Colony.foodAmount += 10
            print "You've found sweet nectar! Your ant has returned to full health and has brought 10 food back to the colony!"
        else:
            print "Ant returned empty-handed!"
def main():
    queen = Colony()
    queen2 = Ant()
    while queen.workerAnts > 0 or queen.foodAmount >= 5:
        print "========================================================"
        print """
        Your colony has %s ants and %s food, Your Majesty.\nWhat would you like to do?\n0: Do nothing.\n1: Breed worker. (Costs 5 food.)""" % (queen.workerAnts, queen.foodAmount)
        answer = int(raw_input(">"))

        if answer != 1 and answer != 0:
            print "Sorry, invalid input!"
        if answer == 0:
            queen.step()
            queen.purge()
        if answer == 1:
            print "Breeding Worker..." 
            queen.breedWorker()
            queen.step()
            queen.purge()

    if queen.workerAnts <= 0 and queen.foodAmount < 5:
        print "I'm sorry! Your colony has died out!"
```

Comment: for starters, you don't call main() anywhere

Comment: Instead of `def main():` write `if __name__ == '__main__':`.

Comment: Your code is a mess, very difficult to follow. I'd wager the issue has something to do with the fact that you are using your class names like variables. Within your `Colony` class, you shouldn't be doing stuff like `Colony.foodAmount`, just use `foodAmount`.

Comment: Perhaps you should team up with [this question's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22286032/iterate-through-a-list-and-delete-certain-elements/22286301#22286301) OP

Comment: One really important point is that you *shouldn't* do e.g. `elif random.randint(0,100)` - this gets a *new random number* each time! Also, `< 40` and `< 5` would both be `True`, this isn't the right way to assign probabilities to events.

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't have constructors (`__init__(self, ...)`) and do not initialize object's properties
2. in methods you call this object property by self.property, not by Classname.property; in python you explicitly pass instance or class object to method, by convention they should be 'self' for instance, or 'cls' for class.
3. If you want use any Colony properties in Ant object or vice versa, you need to explicitly pass the reference, and store it as property. The most sensible would be to create Ant from Colony by calling something `ants.append(Ant(self))`; Ant's constructor should have signature `def **init**(self, colony):'

Answer (score 0):

You made `Ant.health` a class variable (shared between all Ant instances).

As soon as one ant's health goes to 0, they all die.

Here is an improved version. The following code is Python 2 and 3 compatible, and *I think* fixes all the errors!

```
import random
import sys

if sys.hexversion < 0x3000000:
    # Python 2.x
    inp = raw_input
    rng = xrange
else:
    # Python 3.x
    inp = input
    rng = range

def get_int(prompt, lo=None, hi=None):
    """
    Prompt until an integer value in [lo..hi] is entered, then return it
    """
    while True:
        try:
            val = int(inp(prompt))
            if (lo is None or lo <= val) and (hi is None or val <= hi):
                return val
        except ValueError:
            pass

class InsufficientFoodError(Exception):
    pass

class Colony:
    def __init__(self, workers=0, food=10):
        self.food = food + Ant.cost * workers
        self.ants = []
        for i in rng(workers):
            self.add_ant()

    def add_ant(self):
        try:
            self.ants.append(Ant(self))
        except InsufficientFoodError as e:
            print(e)

    def step(self):
        # all ants eat, then all ants forage:
        for ant in self.ants:
            ant.eat()
        for ant in self.ants:
            ant.forage()
        # bring out yer dead!
        self.ants = [ant for ant in self.ants if ant.is_alive()]

    def add_food(self, amount):
        self.food += amount

    def take_food(self, amount):
        amt = min(amount, self.food)
        self.food -= amt
        return amt

    def num_ants(self):
        return len(self.ants)

class Ant:  
    cost = 5
    max_health = 10

    def __init__(self, colony):
        # try to get enough food to produce an ant
        food = colony.take_food(Ant.cost)
        if food < Ant.cost:
            # Failed! return any taken food and throw an error
            colony.add_food(food)
            raise InsufficientFoodError('The colony does not have enough food to make a new Ant')
        else:
            # Success!
            self.colony = colony
            self.health = Ant.max_health

    def eat(self):
        if self.health > 0:
            self.health -= 1 - self.colony.take_food(1)
            if self.health == 0:
                print("An ant starved to death.")

    def forage(self):
        if self.is_alive():
            dice = random.randint(0, 100)
            if dice <= 5:
                self.health = Ant.max_health
                self.colony.add_food(10)
                print("You've found sweet nectar! Your ant has returned to full health and has brought 10 food back to the colony!")
            elif dice <= 40:
                found_food = random.randint(1, 5)
                self.colony.add_food(found_food)
                print("Ant has found {} food!".format(found_food))
            elif dice <= 95:
                print("Ant returned empty-handed!")
            else:
                self.health = 0
                print("Ant has died from a horrible accident!")

    def is_alive(self):
        return self.health > 0

def main():
    colony = Colony()

    while True:
        print(
           "========================================================\n"
           "\n"
           "Your colony has {ants} ants and {food} food, Your Majesty.\n"
           "What would you like to do?\n"
           "  1: Do nothing\n"
           "  2: Breed worker (costs {cost} food)"
           .format(ants=colony.num_ants(), cost=Ant.cost, food=colony.food)
        )
        opt = get_int("> ", 1, 2)

        if opt == 2:
            print("Breeding Worker...")
            colony.add_ant()

        colony.step()

        if colony.num_ants() == 0 and colony.food < Ant.cost:
            print("I'm sorry! Your colony has died out!")
            break

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Indeed, they have made many things class attributes that should probably be instance attributes

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's because of the following line in `def purge(self)`:

```
    Colony.list = Colony.temp
```

The first time `purge()` is ran, it makes both `Colony.list` and `Colony.temp` point to the same array in memory. So the second time you run `purge()`, you go into an infinite loop, where you `for number in Colony.list:` do `Colony.temp.append("ant")`, which actually increases `Colony.list` as well, and the loop never exits, since it will always have a new member.

In python, `for` loops create iterators for the given object (if it's not already an iterator). In every iteration, python will call the iterator's `next()` method (in this case - the list). If `next()` can't yield a new value to iterate over, it raises `StopIteration`, and the loop exits. Don't worry, this exception is automatically handled for you by the `for` statement. In your case, `Colony.list.next()` always finds a new value (since you've just appended to it), and will never reach the end.

To fix your code, try slicing. This means that the array is copied, instead of pointing the two names to the same array:

```
    Colony.list = Colony.temp[:]
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a little off, but seems like it will be a valuable piece of knowledge.
A big issue here is that your classes are being used in an undesirable way.

The main advantage of a class is to hold an instance of variables/functions, such that you can have many independent groupings of them.

By calling `Colony.<var>` you're changing the `var` of the base( or super) class variable. This works if you only want to have one Colony,... but what if you want two,. or three! or a million!!?

Notice how you get an error when you don't enter `self` as the first parameter to your class functions? What you need to realize is that you're passing an instance of your class as the first parameter. This is how the class knows what grouping of variables to use.

say we have a class `Antzilla`

```
class Antzilla:
    antvar = "antzilla var"
    def PrintSuperAntvar(self):
        print Antzilla.antvar

    def PrintInstanceOfAntvar(self):
        print self.antvar
```

notice that `PrintSuperAntvar` calls the base var and that `PrintInstanceOfAntvar` prints an instance of `Antzilla`

If I make `az1` and change `az1.antvar` it will not change the `Antzilla.antvar` value.

```
az1 = Antzilla()
az1.antvar = "new var"


az1.PrintSuperAntvar()
>>> antzilla var
az1.PrintInstanceOfAntvar()
>>> new var
```

I can now create a new `Antzilla` instance with the original starting value because I never changed base class value

```
az2 = Antzilla()
az2.PrintSuperAntvar()
>>> antzilla var
az2.PrintInstanceOfAntvar()
>>> antzilla var
```

However if you were to change this super value then you would see that new `Antzilla`'s start with this new value, but `Antzilla`'s that have been already changed remain the same.

```
Antzilla.antvar = "newest var"
az3 = Antzilla()
az3.PrintSuperAntvar()
>>> newest var
az3.PrintInstanceOfAntvar()
>>> newest var

az1.PrintSuperAntvar()
>>> new var
```

**WATCH OUT!!!** notice what happens when we call `az2`!

```
az2.PrintSuperAntvar()
>>> newest var
```

`az2` was never changed from the super variable, so when we changed `Antzilla.antvar` from `"antzilla var"` to `"newest var"`, `az2` will continue to cling to the super value.

How do we avoid this conflict!? Its simple!

Just add a **constructor** to your class that **copies** the super value, or a new value into its own variable..
If present, the `__init__` function will be called if when you make a new `Antzilla` instance

```
class Antzilla:
    antvar = "antzilla var"

    def __init__(self):
         self.antvar = Antzilla.antvar

    ...
```

You can also add the var as a requirement to your constructor such that every instance is unique.

```
class Antzilla:
    antvar = "antzilla var"

    def __init__(self, antvar ):
         self.antvar = antvar

    ...

az1 = Antzilla("antzilla unique swag")
```

It is important to note however that when dealing with variables like lists, that you will need to specifically create a new list for every instance. Luckily the best place to do this is also the constructor.

So now getting back to your issue,.. for your two classes I would add constructors like this

For Colony:

```
class Colony(object):
    workerAnts = 0
    list = []
    temp = []
    foodAmount = 10

    def __init__(self):
        self.workerAnts = 0
        self.list = []
        self.temp = []
        self.foodAmount = 10

    ....
```

For Ant

```
class Ant(object):  
    health = 10
    def __init__(self):
        self.health = 10
    ....
```

And finally what you need to do before getting into the math or logic errors is replace all the spots where you call a base or super variable with `self` or the name of the variable in the given scope.

ie, things like:

```
 Colony.foodAmount -= 5
```

change to:

```
 self.foodAmount -= 5
```

============================================================================

PS that spot where you write :

```
Colony.temp.append("ant")
```

is actually appending a **string** to your **base** list. You probably want to change that to the constructor for an `Ant`.. which returns a new instance of the `Ant` class and make it add the variable to an instance of `colony` instead of the base `colony`

```
self.temp.append(Ant())
```

============================================================================

Hope this helps!!

Cheers,

Cal